# Spark: retrieving a file saved on the driver

Tags: scala, io, apache-spark

I am using spark in **yarn-cluster mode**. I save some results contained in Strings on the driver node with `import java.io.PrintWriter`.

HOwever, in yarn-cluster mode, the dirver is one of the cluster nodes. And I cannot manage to retrieve these files at the end of the process. I haven't find any yet.

Comment: I can't come up with other idea than to save these files into a shared location. It can be a distributed filesystem, like HDFS, or some fileserver, like ftp.

Answer (score 2):

the best possible solution is to save them on HDFS.

I didn’t tried but you should be able to do this:

sc.textFiles("file://namenode:port/path/to/input")